# Prevent Image Size from Increasing While Dimensions Are Decreased

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing, system.drawing.imaging

I have a function that takes in a byte array of image data and then resizes it so its height and or width are around 200px max.

The function successfully reduces the size of the image (in terms of dimensions), but the size of the file gets drastically increased.

Example: 
Resized an image that is originally 32.2KB with dimensions of 828x251.
The output is an image that is 374KB with dimensions of 577x200.

Below is the function being used:

```
public static string resizeImage(string imgToResize)
{
    try
    {
        string image_info = imgToResize.Split(',')[0];
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(imgToResize.Split(',')[1]));
        System.Drawing.Image converted_image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        int original_width = converted_image.Width;
        int original_height = converted_image.Height;

        // Figure out the ratio
        double ratioX = (double) original_width / (double) original_height;
        double ratioY = (double) original_height / (double) original_width;
        // use whichever multiplier is smaller
        double ratio = ratioX < ratioY ? ratioX : ratioY;

        int new_height = 0;// Convert.ToInt32(original_height * ratio);
        int new_width = 0;// Convert.ToInt32(original_width * ratio);
        // now we can get the new height and width
        if (original_width <= original_height)
        {
            new_width = 200;
            new_height = Convert.ToInt32((decimal)new_width / (decimal)ratio);
        }
        else {
            new_width = Convert.ToInt32((decimal)original_width * (1-(decimal)ratio));
            new_height = 200;
        }


        Size image_size = new Size(new_width, new_height);

        System.Drawing.Image new_image =  (System.Drawing.Image)(new Bitmap(converted_image, image_size));

        using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            new_image.Save(m, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return image_info + "," + base64String;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
    }

    return "";
}
```

Can anyone explain why the file size is getting drastically increased from this reduction in dimensions and how to prevent it (or actually reduce the size of the file in addition to reducing its dimensions)?

Comment: What is the original file format of the image being resized? You are saving the resized image as a bitmap, which is usually much larger than, say, a jpeg. If the original file is a jpeg and the resized file is a bitmap, I wouldn't be surprised that the latter has a larger file size.

Comment: It's a .PNG and I trying to resize it into another .PNG

Comment: No, you don't. You save as BMP which is uncompressed. Do not confuse Bitmap class and BMP file format!!

Comment: *FACE PALM* Doh!

Comment: If you have more formats being handled, you can use `converted_image.RawFormat`; that should be the file format of the file you opened. By the way, you should really put every bitmap you create in a `using` block so they get properly disposed afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saving it as a .bmp, which will have a much larger filesize.

Change the line `new_image.Save(m, ImageFormat.Bmp);` to `new_image.Save(m, ImageFormat.Png);` or `new_image.Save(m);`, which will save it as a .png instead of an uncompressed .bmp (the latter chooses the .png format by default).

See [Image.Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.8) docs for more info.